# how to known the docker pull path of mirror to replace the original address

Tags: docker

I am pulled image failed like this:

```
$ docker pull alpine-bash:3.8
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/alpine-bash/manifests/3.8: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

now I found an mirror:

```
https://dockerhub.azk8s.cn
```

how to pull image from the mirror address? I have tried like this:

```
$ docker pull dockerhub.azk8s.cn/alpine-bash:3.8           
Error response from daemon: manifest for dockerhub.azk8s.cn/alpine-bash:3.8 not found

$ docker pull dockerhub.azk8s.cn/v2/library/alpine-bash:3.8
Error response from daemon: manifest for dockerhub.azk8s.cn/v2/library/alpine-bash:3.8 not found

$ docker pull dockerhub.azk8s.cn/v2/library/alpine-bash/alpine-bash:3.8
Error response from daemon: manifest for dockerhub.azk8s.cn/v2/library/alpine-bash/alpine-bash:3.8 not found
```

Comment: Does `dockerhub.azk8s.cn/library/alpine-bash:3.8` work?  If so, I can explain why.

Comment: no，not works.@DavidMaze